# How to fill the middle table of an n:m association with the methode fooInstance.createBar() with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I want to fill the data into a N:M jointure table with the methods provided by sequelize.
As my data is in `allowNull: false`, i can't add the data afterward :/

Here an exemple of code/BDD:

[image: UML]

my table a:

```js
var A = sequelize.define('A', {
    id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false
    },
    someDataA: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
    },
})

A.associate = function(models) {
        A.belongsToMany(models.B, { 
            through: models.C, 
            foreignKey: 'a_id',
            otherKey: 'b_id',
            as: 'C'
        });
    }
```

my table b:

```js
var B = sequelize.define('B', {
    id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false
    },
    someDataB: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
    },
})
B.associate = function(models) {
        B.belongsToMany(models.A, { 
            through: models.C, 
            foreignKey: 'b_id',
            otherKey: 'a_id',
            as: 'C'
        });
    }
```

my table c:

```js
var C = sequelize.define('C', {
    a_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false
    },
    b_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false
    },
    JointedData: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
    },
})

C.associate = function(models) {
        C.belongsTo(models.A, {
            as: 'A',
            foreignKey: 'a_id'
        });
        C.belongsTo(models.B, {
            as: 'B',
            foreignKey: 'b_id'
        });
    }
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
fooAInstance.createB({somdeDataB: 15}, /* define here the data into JointedData */ {JointedData: 99});
```

How can i achieve something like that???

Thx for your time and answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indicate `through` option like this:

```
await fooAInstance.createB({somdeDataB: 15}, { through: { JointedData: 99 } })
```

See [Advanced Many-to-Many](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html)